# How to show total rows after deleting 1 or more rows then show the Total?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to show total rows after deleting  1 or more rows then show the Total ?

I have a dynamic table that add rows and shows the total rows. How do i show the total after i delete 1 or 2 rows ?

[Table Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5QOc.png)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var table = document.getElementById('table'),rIndex;
$(document).ready(function(){
    var rowCount;

    $(".add-row").bind('click', function() {
        var OS = $("#OS").val();
        var vCPU = $("#vCPU").val();
        var Memory = $("#Memory").val();
        var Val = $("#Val").val();
        var Performance = $("#Performance").val();
        var HighWrite = $("#HighWrite").val();
        var markup 
        = "<tr onclick = 'clickRow(this)'><td><input   type='checkbox'   name='record'></td><td>" + OS + "</td><td>" + vCPU + "</td><td>" + Memory + "</td><td>" + Val + "</td><td>" + Performance + "</td><td>" + HighWrite + "</td></tr>";

        $("table tbody").append(markup);


         rowCount = $('table tbody tr').length;
         rowCount = rowCount-1;
          $('#counter').html(rowCount);


    });

    // Find and remove selected table rows
    $(".delete-row").click(function(){
        $("table tbody").find('input[name="record"]').each(function(){
            if($(this).is(":checked")){

                $(this).parents("tr").remove();


            }
        });
    });



});
```

Comment: please add a jsfiddle along with your question

Answer (score 1):

Slightly modified, your code. You don't need to get length in add, you can just add one to the counter, or subtract one in the case of removal.

```js
var table = document.getElementById('table'),rIndex;

$(document).ready(function(){
    var rowCount  = 0;

    $(".add-row").bind('click', function() {
        var OS = $("#OS").val();
        var vCPU = $("#vCPU").val();
        var Memory = $("#Memory").val();
        var Val = $("#Val").val();
        var Performance = $("#Performance").val();
        var HighWrite = $("#HighWrite").val();
        var markup 
        = "<tr onclick = 'clickRow(this)'><td><input   type='checkbox'   name='record'></td><td>" + OS + "</td><td>" + vCPU + "</td><td>" + Memory + "</td><td>" + Val + "</td><td>" + Performance + "</td><td>" + HighWrite + "</td></tr>";

        $("table tbody").append(markup);


         rowCount++;
          $('#counter').html(rowCount);


    });

    // Find and remove selected table rows
    $(".delete-row").click(function(){
        $("table tbody").find('input[name="record"]').each(function(){
            if($(this).is(":checked")){
                $(this).parents("tr").remove();
                rowCount--;
                $('#counter').html(rowCount);
            }
        });
    });



});
```